# Flask passing a function but the function gets rendered everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I have a flask function called lock(id) and unlock()

```
def lock(roomId):
    RoomTDG.update(roomId,True)

def unlock(roomId):
    RoomTDG.update(roomId, False)
```

I am calling it in my template

`{{ lock(1) }}`

However this piece of code gets always rendered regardless of it being in a jquery if statement or outside. How can I call it when it goes inside the if statement

```
$('#room1').click(function() {
              "{{ lock(1) }}"
              alert("hello");
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code (JQuery or otherwise) runs in the browser, the `{{ lock(1) }}` expression is rendered *on the server*. Creating the template to send to the browser *has* to execute that function then and there, Javascript code in the template is not executed on the server and doesn't influence what `{{ lock(1) }}` outputs.

Only `"None"`, the resulting output in the template, is seen by the JavaScript code.

You'd have to create a new route in your Flask server that the jQuery code then calls via AJAX (using [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), for example).

Comment: so like how can I just call lock(1) if the room1 is clicked , pleaseeeeee??

Comment: what do you mean ?? @Martin Pieters

Comment: @user3450754: I included documentation references; you could read up on  what [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is, for example.

Comment: @user3450754: however, a full tutorial on how to execute an AJAX request is out of the scope of my answer.

Comment: @user3450754: see this other question on the same subject: [Jinja2 : call function on click](//stackoverflow.com/q/37346842)